# Display all emails with the highest id column

Tags: mysql, sql

I apologize if this question has been posted on here in the past. I always do some research before I post on here.

I have a database of emails stored. Each email has multiple rows, so for example the email test@gmail.com could have 4 results. The only thing that is different from the results is the status column. The status values could be "processed", "delivered", "open", "click".

I wanna be able to only display the emails with the highest "id" of their own status.

**Here is my current table**

[image]

**Here is what I'm trying to display.**
[image]

I've tried this query but it just returns only one email with the highest "id" on the whole table.

```
SELECT email, status FROM sendgrid WHERE template_sent_id = '19454767' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: And note that this is the MOST FREQUENTLY ASKED question under the MySQL tag; so I would have to question your intial assertion. Plus, the word 'wanna'; just no.

Comment: Ok lol. I understand that this might be the "MOST FREQUENTLY ASKED" like you say but for myself I couldn't find or figure out the answer but hey... thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT sg.email, sg.status
FROM sendgrid sg
WHERE sg.template_sent_id = 19454767 AND
      sg.timestamp = (SELECT MAX(sg2.timestamp)
                      FROM sendgrid sg2
                      WHERE sg2.template_sent_id = sg.template_sent_id AND
                            sg2.email = sg.email
                     );
```

For performance, you want and index on `sendgrid(template_send_id, email, timestamp)`.